# "Twitter like" follow button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create an like button like twitter, i used from this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.btn-follow').on('mouseover', function(e){
    if ($(this).hasClass('following')){
      $(this).removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-danger').text('UnFollow');
    }
  })
  $('.btn-follow').on('mouseleave',function(e){
    if ($(this).hasClass('following')){
      $(this).text('Following').removeClass('btn-danger').addClass('btn-primary');
    }
  })
  $('.btn-follow').on('click',function(e){
    $(this).toggleClass('following follow')
    if ($(this).hasClass('follow')){
      alert('unfollow')
      $(this).text('Follow').removeClass('btn-danger')
    }else{
      alert('follow')
      $(this).text('Following')
    }
  })
});
```

and in html i have this:

```
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-follow following">Following</button>
    <br />
    <br />
  <button class="btn btn-follow follow">Follow</button>
```

but i think it 's very dirty code and have some bugs. How i can fix this code?

Comment: what bugs do you have>?

Comment: When i click second button, hover not work. How i can rebind a functions?

Comment: Was the `button` an `a` at one time? If so, you replaced the start tags, but you forgot to replace the end tags...

Answer (score 0):

Ok the main problem was **css specificity** not letting `btn-danger` class take any effect over `btn-success`.
So as a solution i used an empty class that i made up. To track if the button is being followed or not.

Whenever i added `btn-success` i added `following` class. And through class, as you did, i was able to track the state of the button.

**With bootstrap!!!**
http://jsfiddle.net/vjZRA/1/

Without bootstrap:http://jsfiddle.net/vjZRA/

Code Below:

```
var btn = $('.btn');
btn.click(h);
btn.hover(hin, hout);

function hin() {
    if (btn.hasClass('follow')) {
        btn.text('Stop Following');
        btn.removeClass('btn-success');
        btn.addClass('btn-danger');
    } else {
        btn.addClass('btn-primary');
    }
}

function hout() {
    if (btn.hasClass('follow')) {
        btn.text('Following');
        btn.removeClass('btn-danger');
        btn.addClass('btn-success follow');
    }
    btn.removeClass('btn-primary');
}

function h() {
    if (btn.hasClass('follow')) {
        btn.removeClass('btn-success follow');
        btn.text('Follow');
        btn.removeClass('btn-danger');
    } else {
        btn.text('Following');
        btn.addClass('btn-success follow');

    }
}
```

and then add css in style tag or wherever you want

`.follow{}`

Comment: i didn't do chaining to keep it clear. I think all improvements should be done once you have you concept and approach to it laid out.

Comment: code really minified: `var _=$(".btn");_.click(function(){_.hasClass("f")?_.removeClass("btn-success f").text("Follow").removeClass("btn-danger"):_.text("Following").addClass("btn-success f")});_.hover(function(){_.hasClass("f")?_.text("Stop Following").removeClass("btn-success").addClass("btn-danger"):_.addClass("btn-primary")},function(){_.hasClass("f")?_.text("Following").removeClass("btn-danger").addClass("btn-success f"):_.removeClass("btn-primary")});

`